# Will I loose all the non-default packages if I upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 using a Live CD/DVD?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, live-cd

I have downloaded the ISO of Ubuntu 12.04. But before I go for an upgrade, I want to know whether I shall lose all those non-default packages including restricted extras if I upgrade using a Live CD/DVD.

While upgrading, I will not have an Internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you'll lose the multiverse and the restricted packages but you can install them again. If you are trying that upgrade with a "live CD" then you can't. Though if you have the alternate iso, then you could avoid wasting a CD by mounting the ISO as a drive with a command like:

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/cdrom
sudo mount -o loop ~/Desktop/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-i386.iso /media/cdrom
```

Then to start the upgrade enter:

```
gksu "sh /media/cdrom/cdromupgrade"
```